# Are there risks to running one computer with two completely different power sources?

Tags: power, inverter, computers

I have experienced two computer power supplies using the same main power utility company here (same breaker, just different circuit). I am planning out an off-grid system, am considering running one power supply of the computer on the main utility power, and 2nd power supply on the off-grid system.

Are there risks or considerations I need to make when using two completely separate power sources?

I hear people recommend pure sine wave inverters for computer equipment off off-grid systems. Are there other risks, and can you explain a bit so I can research deeper? I don't know enough on power, and if the computer will function fine with two completely separate sources of power for the two power supplies.

Thanks for the direction!

Comment: Just to understand, you have a computer with redundant power supplies? That is, you have two power sources connected to the computer and the computer run with either or both powered?

Comment: Inverters produce sine-waves. If you have two in parallel, bad things are going to happen if the sine-wave each one putting out is not identical in phase.

Comment: @DoxyLover Yeah, it's a few GPU mining computer.

Comment: @DKNguyen Ah, okay. Is there a common way to make sure they're in the same phase? I'll check google, but let me know if you have recommendations on preventing that

Comment: The have to be specifically made to be  able to track each other and synch up. It's fundamental to their operation. Can't be done after-the-fact.

Comment: Provided you’re connecting the outputs of the power supplies together and not the inputs, the AC phases don’t matter at all and running one PSU from mains and one from an inverter isn’t a problem.  Where you need to be careful is whether the power supplies themselves are ok to be connected in parallel.  Some servers have redundant power supplies and so would clearly be ok in that configuration but I couldn’t say for certain whether PSUs designed for standalone operation would like this setup.  My feeling is yes, but I’m not certain.

Comment: Many *servers* have dual power supplies designed for exactly this kind of scenario.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The standard way for handling that is to use a (small) UPS and an ATS.

ATS being a fancy word for a (sometimes *huge*, like more than 100A) relay/contactor assembly that switches between power supplies *without ever* make them collide (i.e. a complete break-before-make assurance)

Fancy ATS systems have also a semiconductor based switch to handle the transition without needing a separate UPS (think big SCRs).

Also remember that usually the EMC compliance call for resilience to dips of at least one power cycle, so it helps.